# Assign an init value to my input form and always resulting an Null output

Tags: php, html, forms, input

So I try to create some order form in my website, (p.s. my site is rent a car site), my method is they input their details, and then they go to the review page which is reviewing their order and then submit it so that the detail will go into my desired email. but somehow, at the review page, i set the init value for the forms which I create with the details that was imputed in the form before(Succeed). when i click submit, the details that has been sent into the my email PHP contact form is always set as null, and yet so, my `isset` function will find it wrong and wont do the function. here's the full code

the review page
[Review Page](http://tny.cz/0b40c10c)

the mail-sending php function page
[Mail-Sender form result page](http://tny.cz/cd6ea8a8)

sorry for not using the code sample code in here, because my code is confusing as it contain much `{` and `}` signs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A browser will not post any content from a disabled input. You'll want to use hidden inputs and display the data in text for the user to review.

For example, change it to something like:

```
<tr>
 <td valign="middle" width="200px" height="40px">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="middle" width="700px">
  <?= echo $name; ?>
  <input name="name" id="name"type="hidden" class="inputstyle" value="<?= $name; ?>">
 </td>
</tr>
```